# Rotate Panel in WinForm

Tags: c#

How can i rotate (90 degrees) a panel control? i know it is very simple in WPF but i can't use it.
Do you know such a way for WinForm panel control?
Thanks you all!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you use WPF? You know about ElementHost, right? I'm interested because we're thinking about adding some WPF in our WinForms app, and I'm curious about why you're not able to.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to override the [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx), then manually paint all the controls on the [panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) using GDI.  I have never done a rotate, but I have done some custom repaints for things like dropdowns.  You will need to write custom OnPaints for each control type on the panel.

So more on this as I just tried it my self... I dont think you can custom paint most of the common controls.  WPF is a different animal, and was designed to support this type of thing.  When these controls paint, they do so under the covers and there is nothing you can do.  I was able to paint and rotate the panel, but I was not able to do other controls like a Check Box.

```
    public class RotatePanel : Panel, IRotate
    {

        public RotatePanel() : base()
        {
            Angle = 0;
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                foreach (IRotate control in this.Controls)
                {
                    control.Angle = Angle;
                }
                g.RotateTransform(Angle);
                g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 2f), 4f, 4f, 10f, 10f);
                g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Azure), 2f), 14f, 14f, 30f, 30f);
                g.Flush();
            }
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        }

        public float Angle
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public interface IRotate
    {
        float Angle { get; set; }
    }

   public class RotateCheckBox : CheckBox, IRotate
    {
        public float Angle { get; set; }
        public RotateCheckBox():base()
        {
            Angle = 0;
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            pevent.Graphics.RotateTransform(this.Angle);
            pevent.Graphics.Flush();
            base.OnPaint(pevent);
        }
    }
```